# Javascript Function Onclick change div hight and add hide button replace the more button

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add a hide button to set default size of the div and when click on more it replaces more button with hide button

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function resizeDiv(id) {
        var obj = document.getElementById(id);
        if (obj) {
            obj.setAttribute("style", "height:600px;");


        }
    }
</script>



<button style="margin:10px;" onclick="javascript:resizeDiv('ss');
">More</button>
```

Comment: there are hundreds of examples. DO a google search

Comment: No need for the _javascript:_ unless you have a VBScript as the first script on the page

Answer (score 0):

You likely mean this

```
<style type="text/css">
#ss { display:none  }
</style>    
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("butss").onclick=function() {
    var obj = document.getElementById(this.id.replace("but",""));
    if (obj) {
      var on = this.innerHTML=="More";
      obj.style.display=(on)?"block":"none"; // or obj.style.height=(on)?"600px":"0";
      this.innerHTML=(on)?"Less":"More";
    }
  }
}    
</script>



<button style="margin:10px;" id="butss">More</button>
<div id="ss">Hello</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this:

```
<button style="margin:10px;" onclick="javascript:resizeDiv('ss');if (this.innerHTML == 'More') {this.innerHTML = 'Hide'} else {this.innerHTML = 'Hide'}">More</button>
```